# Weird shading after using solidify modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm making a simple cuboidal room, but as soon as I solidify my mesh it gets weird black patches around the corners.

If I turn fill rim to off it looks good, but obviously I want to fill the rims. I guess the normals are flipped or something leading to a lighting issue. It also persists in final rendered version

**From outside**

Notice the dark shade just above the 3D cursor

[image]

**From inside**

Again above the 3d cursor

[image]

[**File**](http://pasteall.org/blend/34574).

Comment: Those problems are caused by using N-gons with vertices that are not on the same plane, creating **NON PLANAR** geometry. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18055/strange-lighting-problem-with-normals/18058#18058 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/face-behavior-not-equal-after-loop-cut/23602#23602

Comment: @cegaton doing split non planar faces did abolutely nothing

Comment: @user1062760 It's being caused by those ngons, either add an edge split modifier, shade the model flat or try and get some quads there. The marked answer has several links to similar questions, try to read them all. http://pasteall.org/blend/34575