# UVs looking weird when using the solidify modifier

Tags: uv, modifiers

I'm working on an animation of paper sheets.
I want to keep things very simple since I'll have to animate a lot of them and don't want to complexify things if I don't need to.
So my mesh is just a subdivised rectangle :

[image]

But when I use a solidify modifier (to give the sheet some thickness), the edges of my paper are getting weird :

[image]

which is not the case without the modifier:

[image]

Does anyone knows what causes this and how could I avoid it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/weird-shading-after-using-solidify-modifier

Answer (score 1):

Your flat mesh likely has smooth shading enabled, which only becomes visible once you give it thickness. In object mode you can select your object and applied flat shading by using *Object > Shade Flat*.

Comment: Yes, I have used Smooth shading because I need to curve my paper.  Any chance of having the best of both worlds ?

Comment: @gordie Then you would need to add edge loops to all four sides that are close to the outer border. Or you use auto-smooth with an adjusted angle which may not be ideal for animation.

Comment: Ok, found the answer in the duplicates : just add a EdgeSplit modifier.  Thanks all !

Comment: @gordie yes, that works too.